# Formula to search rows for certain value and get corresponding cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to write a formula to search for all cells in a certain range (a certain range in a column), get the row id of any cell that matches a certain value, then get the values (of all the cells that matched) from a different column.

Something like:

```
    A     B
1   ABC   123
2   DEF   456
3   GHI   789
4   ABC   100
```

Now what I need is to look in A1:A4 for "ABC" which will return A1 and A4, and get the value of B1 and B4. I couldn't figure it out.

I know I can do this in VBA. But it won't update on changing like formulas do.

Comment: How/where do you input the "question" (e.g. "ABC"), and how do you show the output? There's more to your spreadsheet...

Comment: Also, if you have an idea of where to start, it's best to give it a go, then come back with what you have tried and the specific problems you are encountering. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to SO!

Comment: What do you mean by how/where? The output is to be shown in a range of cells as a formula array.

Comment: @Alex I mean 1) How do you capture the input? Do you type it into cell F1 for example? 2) Where do you want to see the output? If input = "ABC" do you display "123" in C1 and "100" in C4? Or do you display those values combined into a single cell somewhere, like "123100"?

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 2 To Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "ABC" Then
        MsgBox Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
Next I
```

This code find value "ABC" in "A" column and return "B" column row value.

Comment: Your code might work, but again, my problem with VBA is that it doesn't update automatically if, for example, another row is edited with "ABC".