# VBA Excel copy autosum data to the specified cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort the exercise, in which the auto summarize data will be copied straight to the cell related from the input-based cell in the row.
[image]

[image]

In the first sheet I have the results of my search across all workbooks in the directory applying the string (code) 4008 in the input.

Next I would like to autosum all these values in the first cell after the last row under E column and paste it directly to the cell, which corresponds to the row, where the code 4008 can be found.

```
 My code looks like this:

 Sub SearchFolders()

 Dim wbAct As Workbook, pathMainWb As String, fldrPath As String
 Dim bom As String, scrUpdt, WsOut As Worksheet, colFiles As Collection, f As Object
 Dim xBol As Boolean, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arrWs
 Dim matchedCells As Collection, Cell, numHits As Long, summRow As Long    
 Set wbAct = ActiveWorkbook
 pathMainWb = wbAct.FullName '<<<<

 On Error GoTo ErrHandler

 fldrPath = UserSelectFolder("Select a folder")
If Len(fldrPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

'get all files in the selected folder
 Set colFiles = GetFileMatches(fldrPath, "*.xls*", False) 'False=no subfolders
 If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Excel files found in selected folder"
    Exit Sub
End If

bom = InputBox("Please provide the Code")

scrUpdt = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")

summRow = 1
'sheet names to scan
arrWs = Array("Civils Work Order", "Cable Work Order", "BoM")

WsOut.Cells(summRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Workbook", "Worksheet", _
                    "Cell", "Text in Cell", "Values corresponding")
For Each f In colFiles
    xBol = (f.Path = pathMainWb)  'file already open?
    If xBol Then
        Set wb = wbAct
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=f.Path, UpdateLinks:=0, _
                                 ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
    End If
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        'are we interested in this sheet?
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, arrWs, 0)) Then
            Set matchedCells = FindAll(ws.UsedRange, bom) 'get all cells with bom
            If matchedCells.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Cell In matchedCells
                    summRow = summRow + 1
                    WsOut.Cells(summRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
                        Array(wb.Name, ws.Name, Cell.Address, Cell.Value, _
                                Cell.EntireRow.Range("F1").Value)
                
                    numHits = numHits + 1
                Next Cell     'next match
            End If            'any bom matches
        End If                'matched sheet name
    Next ws
    If Not xBol Then wb.Close False 'need to close this workbook?
Next f

With WsOut
Dim lastRow As Long
.Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E2:E" & lastRow + 1))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("I1").Value = .Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value

 For i = 2 To Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
 If Range("A" & i).Value = bom Then
      Range("F" & i).Value = WsOut.Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value
 End If
 Next i
End With

    
MsgBox numHits & " cells have been found", , "Calculator"

ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = scrUpdt
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

The first question is:

1. Why the autosum cannot work when outside of `ActiveSheet`? (following this thread [Can't copy value from the Last Row to other worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74851270/cant-copy-value-from-the-last-row-to-other-worksheet)  )
2. How could I provide the summed value to the cell I want. When applying this solution:
   [Formula to search rows for certain value and get corresponding cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264680/formula-to-search-rows-for-certain-value-and-get-corresponding-cells)
   the Msgbox throws the current value under the cell pointed out in the second image. When I appy the autosum from other sheet it shows "false"?

Is there a chance to make this value copied directly to the cell appropriat for the given code applied?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using application functions or things like that, even while using `With WsOut... End With` you need to keep using the indirect reference (I don't know the correct terminology) with `.Range` instead of the normal `Range`

```
Sub testSum()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("MOSTEST.xlsx")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Testsheet")
    
    ws.Range("C39").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C29:C38")) 'Not just Range()
    MsgBox ("The sum is = " & ws.Range("C39").Value)
    ws.Range("C39").Clear
    
    With ws
        .Range("C39").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("C29:C38")) 'Not just Range()
        MsgBox ("The sum is = " & .Range("C39").Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Both of these work just fine even if the workbook isn't active.

So in your case if you change

```
.Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E2:E" & lastRow + 1))
'into 
.Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("E2:E" & lastRow))
```

it should work as intended :)

Comment: It doesn't work at all, unfortunately. Moreover, the code doesn't match my situation either.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific than that since you're having issues with the Sum which I addressed so how does it not match your situation, I used your code? Have you checked the value while walking through your code? I also just noticed that you can't Sum up the cell that contains the Sum. I'll edit the correction.

Comment: `.Range` is the fully referenced syntax, which refers back to the object in `With Object`. If you use the unreferenced `Range`, Excel doesn't know what sheet you're talking about, so it assumes you mean the active sheet. If you don't mean the active sheet, the result is wrong.